# Vacuous definition - annoying condition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Can you give me an example of a point of a discrete dynamical system  that is neither a fixed point or periodic point, nor in the orbit of a periodic fixed point, but fulfills the definition of either "stable", "attracting" or "asymptotically stable"?
(Pick your favorite way to define these three concepts, as long as you use first-principle definitions and not those where you use eigenvalues, which are actually a consequence of the former, as there are small variations between books.)

How about continuous systems and equilibrium points and periodic solutions?
        How about one-dimensional vs. multidimensional discrete/continuous systems?

I'm asking this,  because these concepts three usually are only defined in case of discrete systems for fixed points, periodic points and orbits of periodic points - though one could define them actually for *any* set of points $S\subseteq M$. (And similar considerations hold for continuous systems.)
So the question is, if for any other (set of) point(s), these definitions would always be vacuous (then I'd ask a proof that for points that are neither fixed nor periodc in which case it would make sense to formulated the definition of these concepts only for such restricted classes of points.

Comment: Note that usual definition of Lyapunov stability basically has no restriction on what trajectory you are interested in. But you can always transform the system in such a way that you study a stability of an equilibrium. Namely, if you have system $\dot{x} = F(x, t)$ with trajectory $\gamma(t)$, by change of coordinates $x(t) = \delta(t) + \gamma(t)$ you have new system $\dot{\delta} = F(\delta + \gamma(t)) - F(\gamma(t))$. It has a solution $\delta(t) \equiv 0$ which is an equilibrium. It has exactly the same stability properties as trajectory $\gamma(t)$ of original system.

Comment: @Evgeny Hm...this is a good point and basically settles the case for continuous systems. Is such a theorem not available in the discrete case?

Comment: I think this could be done, but non-autonomous discrete system is even nastier than non-autonomous continuous time system. Also, I've made a slight mistake in previous comment: should be $\dot{\delta} = F(\delta + \gamma(t), t) - F(\gamma(t), t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me summarize my comments in an answer.
A pretty simple example of a disrete dynamical system with non-trivial (i.e., not a fixed or periodic point) attractor would be the following:
$$ \overline{r} = 1 + \alpha (r - 1), \;  \overline{\phi} = \phi + \theta \cdot \frac{1+r^2}{2} \mod 2\pi,$$
where $0 < \alpha <1, \; r \in \mathbb{R}, \; \phi \in \mathbb{S}^1$ and $\frac{\theta}{\pi} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$. The dynamics for $r$ can be analyzed separately from dynamics of $\phi$: it is a linear monotonous mapping which has exactly one fixed point at $r=1$ and no other periodic or fixed points. So, if any periodic points of full mapping do exist, they must be contained in $r=1$. Let's see what happens when $r =1$: $(1, \tilde{\phi}) \mapsto (1, \tilde{\phi} + \theta \mod 2\pi)$, so the set $r =1$ is an invariant set. Because of 
monotonicity, it is possible to show that the image of any set $\alpha < r < 
\beta$ with $\alpha < 1 < \beta$ lies in the interior of itself. You can recognize that these properties are enough to call $r = 1$ an attractor in the common sense (see [the beginning of Scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Attractor#Classical_Attracting_Sets:_Three_equivalent_definitions)). However, what happens exactly on the attractor? As we've already shown, the dynamics on this attractor is described by the mapping $\tilde{\phi} \mapsto \tilde{\phi} + \theta \mod 2\pi$. This is known as an [irrational rotation of a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation), and for our choice of $\theta$ ($\theta$ and $2\pi$ are rationally inconsummerate, i.e. $\theta / \pi \not \in \mathbb{Q}$) it has no periodic or fixed points.

Comment: Great example! Since all the example mentioned below in the comments, and this one too, is on too dimensions, invariant sets which don't solely consist of  fixed or periodic orbits can only happen in dimension 2 or higher, right?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that. I don't really know what is the structure of attractors for non-monotonous mappings of intervals: do they have periodic points inside of them or not? For example, are there any periodic orbits in the attractor of logistic map when $r = 4$? I can't say that right now, but hopefully someone could say here something about that.

Comment: The Denjoy example (see, e.g., pp. 403-405 of Katok and Hasselblatt's [Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Dynamical-Encyclopedia-Mathematics-Applications/dp/0521575575)) can be a source of "nontrivial" invariant sets for $C^{1+\alpha}$ diffeomorphisms of a circle (in particular, see Proposition 12.2.2 on p. 405).

Comment: @user539887 That was my first thought initially. However, quick glance at [de Melo - van Strien book](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~svanstri/Files/demelo-strien.pdf) haven't found any reference about whether this set is attracting or not. It would be nice to know if it can be attracting. It is already a nice example of diffeomorphism of a circle with no periodic or fixed points which doesn't have everywhere dense orbit.

Comment: @Evgeny No, I don't claim that it is an attractor, at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let me fix a discrete dynamical system, regarding it as a homeomorphism $f : X \to X$ of a topological space $X$. (One could also have this discussion for continuous self-maps that are not homeomorphisms, but that introduces complications that I would like to ignore).

And I'm going to stick with the concept of "attracting", since I'm not sure that I can guess what you might mean by "stable" or "asymptotically stable".

The concept of "attracting" doesn't make much sense unless you apply it to a subset $C \subset X$ which is invariant under the map $f$, meaning that $f(C)$. This explains, in part, why a fixed point or a periodic orbit is often used when discussing the "attracting" concept: a point is invariant if and only if it is fixed; a finite set is invariant if and only if it is a finite union of periodic orbits.

So now I can define an attracting invariant set:

> An invariant set $C \subset X$ is attracting if and only if there exists an open set $V \subset X$ such that $C \subset V$, and such that for any open set $U \subset V$, if $C \subset U$ then there exists an integer $n > 0$ such that $f^n(V) \subset U$. The open set $V$ is called an *attracting neighborhood* for $C$.

Now, I suppose that you could formulate this definition even in the case that $C$ was not known to be an invariant set.

However, if you added a few more hypotheses then invariance of $C$ would be a *consequence* of this definition. For example, let's suppose that $X$ is a metric space. If $C \subset X$ is a closed subset then $C$ is equal to the intersection of all open sets $V$ that contain $C$, and from this one can easily show that if $C$ is an attractor then $C$ is an invariant set. In particular, a point (or finite subset) is an attractor only if it is an invariant set.

Furthermore, if $A \subset X$ is an arbitrary subset then one can show that $A$ is an attractor (according to the above definition) if and only if its closure $C = \overline A$ is an attractor, implying that $C$ is invariant, and therefore implying that $A$ is a dense subset of a closed, invariant, attracting set $C$.

So, to study attractors in a metric space, you might as well restrict your attention to invariant sets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (With stable point I meant a point $_x0$ such that if you prescribe any  $\varepsilon$, you can always specify a $\delta$, such that starting $\delta$-far from $x_0$ all my iterations stay $\varepsilon$-close to $x_0$; asymptotically stable for a point $p$ means, according to my textbook, that $p$ is attracting + stable. But $p$ to be attracting on the other hand was defined by saying that the set $W^+(p)$ of all points that converge to $p$ is a neighborhood for $p$.)

Comment: There are a few open issue though, and I would be delighted if you can address them - and please feel free to be explicit in listing technical conditions; I'm a grad student and I find it actually easier, if I'm just being given the complete technical hard stuff: 1) In the end you stated basically the proposition *An attractor in a discrete dynamical system on a metric space, given by a homeomorphism, is invariant*. Are there any technical conditions that are missing, or is this statement true as it is?

Comment: 2) Is 1) true if we simply require $f$ to be a continuous self-map? If not, can you give me an example of an attractor that is not invariant?

Comment: 3) Is the proposition still true for $f$ merely being a continuous self-map, that *In a discrete dynamical system, all invariant sets are either fixed points or unions of periodic orbits*? If not, can you please give me an example an attracting point that is neither? This is basically what I'm after.

Comment: 4) Your definition is "attracting" seems actually identical to my definition of "stable" in the first comment - or are they actually different?

Comment: I'm willing to award a bounty (though you'd probably don't need it) and endless gratitude, if you can help me out with these questions, because I really need to sort these definitional problems out.

Comment: By the way, if you are going to study contemporary dynamical systems and nonlinear dynamics texts, there are already few established definitions of attractors. Some of them are listed [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Attractor) (Ruelle-Takens attractor, statistical attractor), some of them (Milnor attractor) are not.

Comment: Your definition of "attracting basin" is pretty nonstandard, I'm afraid. Take $X=[-1,1]$, $f(x)=x^3$, $C=\{0\}$. Then for $V$ you can take any interval of the form $(a,b)$ with $-1<a<0<b<1$ but **NOT** $(-1,1)$ (since $f((-1,1))=(-1,1)$), whereas it is just $(-1,1)$ that is usually called the attraction basin of the attractor $\{0\}$.

Comment: @user539887 Yeah, so, "attracting basin" is not what I should have written. I changed the terminology to "attracting neighborhood". The "attracting basin" would be the union of all attracting neighborhoods.

Comment: @temo 1) holds only for attractors that are closed sets. I'd have to think more about 2). In 3), it is *not* true that all invariant sets are either fixed points or unions of periodic orbits, far from it. In 4), I don't see a mathematical definition of "stable" in your question, so it's hard to say.

Comment: @Evgeny But could you give me a conrete, as simple as possible example of an attracting set/point that is not a fixed point or orbit of a periodic point, as this was what my question was about originally, as this was what by question is actually about? (I do not need an attractor, which is, as I learned, an attracting set + additional hypotheses, just an attracting set would suffice.) In your link it is mentioned that Fig. 4 might be such a set, but there is no proof of the existence of the attracting set, just a picture, [...]

Comment: [...] and also no mentioning which points are those that are not fixed points/not orbits of periodic points. My main motivation is just to understand the foundational definitions better.

Comment: @user539887 Thanks for pointing that out; since  many authors, also when comparing books, come up with their own definition and don't give concrete examples, understand various definitions is quite hard (hence my question being about a concrete example, for which I'm actually still waiting :( ). Perhaps you know a concrete, ideally simple example of a attracting set (stable point would also do), that is neither a fixed point nor orbit of a periodic point?

Comment: @LeeMosher I gave, as indicated, the definition a point being "stable" in my first comment, not in my question. Ok, so now I know various theoretical constraints for different cases of $f$ when a set can be attracting. But coming back to my question, I'm still missing an example, as I asked for in the first sentence of my questions, resp. as in comment "3)".  I am sorry for encroaching on your time, but I'm afraid my question as of yet unresolved.

Comment: @temo I don't know what you mean by "concrete", but a simple (indeed, trivial) example is the following. Take a homeomorphism $f$ of a compact metric space $X$, with as wild behavior as you wish. Then $X\times\{0\}$ is an attractor (in any sense you can find in the literature, I think) for the DS given on $X\times[-1,1]$ by $F(x,y)=(f(x),y^3)$.

Comment: @user539887 This is a good example, thanks a lot! This is a small step forward for me! Unfortunatately I saw I made a small error in my comment, since I wrote "attracting set" there, instead of "attracting point". Is it possible to construct other simple example where the set in question is just a single point? I have the feeling that two or more dimensions are requires for such kinds of examples - or is it possible (even if we stick with "attracting set" than "attracting point") to construct them for metric spaces that are numeric intervals as well?

Comment: Again an extremely trivial example: take, in "my" example, $X=\{0,1\}$ with $f$ the nontrivial permutation. Then $\{(0,0)\}$ is not invariant, however attracting in a sense (the analog in the theory of ODEs is called *orbital asymptotic stability*: the orbit is asymptotically stable). But I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @user539887 Hm... this is an interesting example - but isn't the point $(0,0)$ still periodic (since $F(F(0,0)=F(1,0)=(0,0)$) ? Such types of points (fixed, periodic) I actually what I wanted to exclude, as stated in my first comment to you.

Comment: Sorry for the many points of confusion - to clarify everything hopefully, best replace my sentence from that comment, "*example of a attracting set (stable point would also do), that is neither a fixed point nor orbit of a periodic point*", with "*example of a attracting point (stable point would also do), that is neither a fixed point nor contained in an orbit of a periodic point*".
Related question: Do you know of a text (book/article/blog; anything really), which illustrates all the various definitions for stability (incl. orbital asymptotic stability) with examples?

Comment: If you want an example of attracting set that doesn't consist of fixed or periodic orbits, then [an invariant torus](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Neimark-Sacker_bifurcation) is a such example. It naturally occurs in discrete mappings and for some parameter values dynamics on this torus has no fixed or periodic points (similar to [irrational rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation)).

Comment: Take just $X=[0,1]$, $f(x)=x^2$. Then any $x\in[0,1)$ is (in some sense, to be defined yet!) asymptotically stable. And this should be an example showing that, without (some form of, at lest) invariance of an attractor the attracitivity/asymptotic stability becomes too blunt a tool.

Comment: @user539887 I wish I could upvote your example, because it (alongside your comment about the necessity of invariance) made me realize a thinking error that I made, that became apparent only when I read your example! You have my earnest gratitude.

Comment: @Evgeny user539887 made me finally realize that what I actually was after was an example of an invariant set, that doesn't consist of fixed or periodic orbits - which is exactly what you provided me with. Could you give me maybe quote a simpler instance of these examples for discrete systems? The ones from the link are only for continuous systems - and they are also pretty complicated to understand, so I'm not sure how I could construct one myself in the case of discrete systems. If you can write up something like that in a toy example as an answer, I'd immediately accept and upvote it.

Comment: By the way, when you feel you want to ask extended followup questions, you should not do so in comments. Instead, pick your favorite answer to your present question, and then ask a new question. That way your new question, and its answer, won't be buried in comments where few can benefit from them.